# sum and join in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I don't understand why my solution is not working.

I am trying to count the number of employees by department in a database.

There are two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT
(
    NAME VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
    NAME VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    DEPARTMENT INT NOT NULL REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(ID)
);
```

and I have created a view to show the number of employees in departments.

```
CREATE 
OR REPLACE VIEW VIEW_NB AS 
SELECT
   DEPARTMENT.NAME AS DEPARTEMENT,
   count(*) AS nb 
FROM
   DEPARTMENT 
   LEFT JOIN
      EMPLOYEE 
      ON DEPARTMENT.ID = EMPLOYEE.DEPARTMENT 
GROUP BY
   DEPARTMENT.ID,
   DEPARTMENT.NAME;
SELECT
   ADD_DEPARTMENT('FRANCE', 10);
SELECT
   ADD_DEPARTMENT('SPAIN', 100);
SELECT
   ADD_EMPLOYEE('JOSE', 10);
```

result is

```
 departement | nb 
-------------+----
 FRANCE      |  1
 SPAIN       |  1
```

but it should be

```
 departement | nb 
-------------+----
 FRANCE      |  0
 SPAIN       |  1
```

I understand the need to use left joins.
However my view has at least 1 employee for every department, even when they don't have employee.

Did I miss something? If yes what?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT.NAME AS DEPARTEMENT, count(EMPLOYEE.DEPARTMENT) AS nb
FROM DEPARTMENT
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE
ON DEPARTMENT.ID = EMPLOYEE.DEPARTMENT
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT.ID, DEPARTMENT.NAME;
```

The reason you're getting 1 as a count is because you used `*` , which means - count any record as 1 no matter the data. `COUNT()` ignore `NULL` by default, so all you have to do is provide one of the right(detail) table columns inside it .

Answer (score 1):

Change first line

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT.NAME AS DEPARTEMENT, count(*) AS nb
FROM DEPARTMENT
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE
ON DEPARTMENT.ID = EMPLOYEE.DEPARTMENT
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT.ID, DEPARTMENT.NAME;
```

TO

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT.NAME AS DEPARTEMENT, count(EMPLOYEE.DEPARTMENT) AS nb
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to count the rows from the "outer" table. Because aggregates ignore NULL values, those rows that did no have a match in the `employee` table will be ignored by the `count()` function:

```
SELECT department.name AS departement,
       count(employee.department) AS nb
FROM department
  LEFT JOIN employee ON department.id = employee.department
GROUP BY department.id,
         department.name;
```